# jsoup code to replace the code or add remove

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, jsoup, lucee

i am scraping a page which is working very well and i can modify the elements which i need, except i have thiis issue

I was going through the documentation and could not find anywwhere how can i modify and element from

```
<colgroup>
  <col width="12%"> 
  <col width="9%"> 
  <col width="17%"> 
  <col width="14%"> 
  <col width="14%"> 
  <col width="9%"> 
  <col width="9%"> 
  <col width="11%"> 
  <col width="5%"> 
 </colgroup>
```

to convert that into the `tbody` and `th` elements like below

```
<thead>
  <th width="12%"> any other name1</th>
  <th width="9%"> any other name2</th>
  <th width="17%"> any other name3</th>
  <th width="14%"> any other name4</th>
  <th width="14%"> any other name5</th>
  <th width="9%"> any other name6</th>
  <th width="9%"> any other name7</th>
  <th width="11%"> any other name8</th>
  <th width="5%"> name</th>
 </thead>
```

i tried removing it

```
TheTable.select("colgroup").remove();
```

but if i remove how do i add what i needed.

remove works, but add is easy then modify, i can do that one too

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't change these elements (before jsoup) by using replacenocase or rereplacenocase (regex)?

Comment: there is no reason, but how to do that, i can modify my code

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to convert from the original and what your output looks like now? Maybe then someone can fill in the blanks.